# InitialAdminPassword file is not created in jenkins folder in windows 10 os

Tags: jenkins

The Jenkins installation seems like it went fine but when I launch the `localhost:8080`, Jenkins is asking for password. However, I am not able to find the `initialAdminPassword` file in my system. I checked it multiple times; it seems that this file does not exist. Therefore, what is the issue and how do I get the initial Jenkins login password?

```
    Feb 06, 2018 6:56:46 PM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
    WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\winstone\jenkins.war
    Feb 06, 2018 6:56:47 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
    INFO: Logging initialized @3166ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
    Feb 06, 2018 6:56:48 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
    INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
    WARNING: Empty contextPath
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
    INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
    INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
    INFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Feb 06, 2018 6:57:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
    INFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:09 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavenging
    INFO: Scavenging every 600000ms
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
    INFO: Started w.@f27d66{/,file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war}
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStop
    INFO: Stopped ServerConnector@1cd604c{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper stopScavenging
    INFO: Stopped scavenging
    Feb 06, 2018 6:57:10 PM hudson.WebAppMain contextDestroyed
    INFO: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
    java.lang.Throwable: reason
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1507)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:927)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
    at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:307)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:167)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Main._main(Main.java:294)
    at Main.main(Main.java:132)

Feb 06, 2018 6:57:10 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStop
INFO: Stopped w.@f27d66{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war}
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:560)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Feb 06, 2018 6:57:10 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Main._main(Main.java:294)
    at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Feb 06, 2018 6:57:10 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Main._main(Main.java:294)
    at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Image below]

If you are unable to find the secret file, please uninstall and re-install Jenkins again. Else, delete the `.jenkins` folder in `C:\Users\...\.jenkins\secrets`.

===============

Are you using `jenkins.war` or `jenkins.exe` to install? If you are using `jenkins.exe`, try to download `jenkins.war` from [Jenkins war](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/).

Open Command Prompt, run `java -jar jenkins.war`.
Click on the images to see the oputput

[image: Command Prompt Image1]

[image: Command Prompt Image2]

[image: Initial Password path shown in the command prompt]

Open browser with URL `localhost:8080/`

[image: Browser]

Comment: I tried multiple times reinstalling and repairing, but still the secrets folder is not created. Checked the entire C drive (including the users folder), but no luck.

Comment: This has helped me. Thanks alot

Answer (score 17):

I was having a similar problem on windows where the folder was missing.
I went to `C:\Program Files\Jenkins` and opened `jenkins.err.log`
It had the key that I needed to proceed.

Comment: Thank you! Opened jenkins.err.log and found the password.

Answer (score 4):

see the file `"C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.err.log"`

It has initialpassword before making entry into file.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the issue is that the 8080 port is occupied, so i have used 8081 and its working good.

Answer (score 1):

Check if another service is using port 8080. For me I had to stop the service which i dont really need at the moment and  re-run java -jar jenkins.war. with this it created the secret folder where i found the default password

Answer (score 1):

for me did not show the "secret" folder ,and didn't show the "config.xml" file too ,and inside the users folder too was not showing any thing that can help me, so i did the following steps:

> 1. i changed the port number from 8080 to 8085 from the "jenkins.xml" 
>       (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins)
> 2. restart the computer
> 3. after boot up with browser i tried to go "http://localhost:8085/"

then everything solved ,now is showing the starter page of jenkins and the secret folder is created inside the jenkins folder too.

Answer (score 0):

1. give command `sudo su` to login as super user
2. change to secrets folder
   `cd secrets`
3. `cat initialAdminPassword`

Comment: OP already explained his solution which indicates that yours would not work.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it's in `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\secrets`, as I personally experienced.
This is shown as:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Dear @jrs please answer questions with more details. Thanks!

Comment: in my case i used to install with system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was selected port which was already in use.
Reinstalling and configuring with different port fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Jenkins** on **Docker** try using

```
docker exec -u 0 -it name_of_jenkins_container bash
```

or

```
docker exec -u 0 -it name_of_jenkins_container /bin/bash
```

it will login to this container as **root** user.

Answer (score 0):

This file "initialAdminPassword" can be found at C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\secrets location.

Also, if the installation was successful, this password can be found on the log file as well at C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.err.log.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).